# Woocommerce shortcode orderby price is not working

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have spend hours yesterday solving my problem but it didn't work. 
I want to sort my product of a specific brand on price (low to high), all other sorting options work fine title, id, etc.. But my self declared $arg regular_price won't work.

I have added this code to functions.php in my theme map:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_orderby' );
function woocommerce_shortcode_products_orderby( $args ) 
{  $standard_array = array('menu_order','title','date','rand','id');    
if( isset( $args['orderby'] ) && !in_array( $args['orderby'], $standard_array ) ) 
{  $args['regular_price'] = $args['orderby'];       
   $args['orderby']  = 'meta_value_num'; }  
  return $args;}
```

And I use this shortcode :

```
[product_attribute attribute="merk" filter="bait footwear" per_page="80" columns="4" orderby="regular_price" order="asc"]
```

The result is here:
http://vintagekledingwinkel.nl/aanbiedingen/bait-footwear/

What am i missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_orderby' );

    function woocommerce_shortcode_products_orderby( $args ) {

        $standard_array = array('menu_order','title','date','rand','id');

        if( isset( $args['orderby'] ) && !in_array( $args['orderby'], $standard_array ) ) {
            $args['meta_key'] = $args['orderby'];
            $args['orderby']  = '_regular_price'; 
        }

        return $args;

    }
```

And use below short code:

```
[product_attribute attribute="merk" filter="bait footwear" per_page="80" columns="4" orderby="_regular_price" order="asc"]
```

Let me know the output.

Comment: Unfortunately this gives the same output.

Comment: You can accept my answer by marking RIGHT sign so that any other come in similar situation then they can find it useful. Happy Coding ..

Comment: @ArnoEbben Thanks ! You took me to 1300+ Reputation :)

Comment: It is working on one website but the same code is not working on an other website, i don't get it? Also when i use this shortcode it is also not working on both websites: [product_category category="speelgoed" per_page="8" columns="4"  orderby="_regular_price" order="asc"]

Comment: It should work for both .. Make sure you are giving right parameters in shortcode . And if there are sale products in that category then you need to change it to `_sale_price` in both code as well as in shortcode.